# Receiving player and hero level 2 rewards on higher levels

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Every so often after playing a game, the post-game screen suggests I just reached Player Level 2, receiving the corresponding 1000 gold reward. However, I am actually level 25. A similar thing is going on for my hero: I get level 2 rewards even though my Diablo is level 4. Is this a bug? Or am I missing some kind of feature?

Here's a screenshot of such a post-game situation:

[image: post game showing level 2 rewards]

And here's a screenshot of my Player Progression right after that:

[image: Player progression]

As you can see, I *am* still level 25, have *not* just levelled nor am I about to (or would I get any reward if I would). Strange thing is (and I'm not complaining): it seems I get to keep the gold.

And like I mentioned, same thing happens for my hero. That is, post-game tells me I reached level 2, but right afterward I can see on my profile that he's in fact level 4:

[image: level 4 diablo]

This happened to me on more than one occasion (about three or four times now, I think).

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I thinks this is a bug. This is a game in beta, right?. I saw once a similar level-advancing-circle, that showed that my level has been increased from 0 to 1 (or 2) when my real level was ~30. But I didn't received any rewards then AFAIR.

Comment: Pre released from a closed beta should point to the developer website to address all possible bug issues.

Comment: @klm123 Thanks for your confirmation. Would you consider putting it up as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @Jeroen, thank you, but I don't think that is worth to be an answer, I'm not fully sure that I saw what I saw, I didn't pay too much attention to this, plus you describe a little bit different behaviour (you got rewards, I didn't).

Comment: I think you should submit a bug report and put the answer of developer as an answer to this question on stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no documented change about this and since it makes no sense, yes, **it is a bug**.

Given the numerous posts in /r/heroesofthestorm complaining about how gold gaining was so slow during the alpha, I wouldn't be surprised if players keep their voices down about this bug to get back at Blizzard:)